# yolov7 pose estimation RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 24 and 23

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I used the [code](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/tools/keypoint.ipynb) to test yolov7 pose estimation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import cv2
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
from utils.datasets import letterbox
from utils.general import non_max_suppression_kpt
from utils.plots import output_to_keypoint, plot_skeleton_kpts
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
weigths = torch.load('yolov7-w6-pose.pt', map_location=device)
model = weigths['model']
_ = model.float().eval()

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.half().to(device)
image = cv2.imread('./person.jpg')
image = letterbox(image, 960, stride=32, auto=True)[0] #original is stride=64
image_ = image.copy()
image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)
image = torch.tensor(np.array([image.numpy()]))

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    image = image.half().to(device)   
output, _ = model(image)
output = non_max_suppression_kpt(output, 0.25, 0.65, nc=model.yaml['nc'], nkpt=model.yaml['nkpt'], kpt_label=True)
with torch.no_grad():
    output = output_to_keypoint(output)
nimg = image[0].permute(1, 2, 0) * 255
nimg = nimg.cpu().numpy().astype(np.uint8)
nimg = cv2.cvtColor(nimg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
for idx in range(output.shape[0]):
    plot_skeleton_kpts(nimg, output[idx, 7:].T, 3)
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(nimg)
plt.show()
```

When I change stride to 32:
`image = letterbox(image, 960, stride=64, auto=True)[0]`  to

`image = letterbox(image, 960, stride=32, auto=True)[0]`
The error message is:RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 2. Got 24 and 23 (The offending index is 0)

Why can't I use `stride=32`?